# UITableViewCell custom (nib)

Tags: iphone, cell

i have make a custom cell in nib file with delegate.

I have define a .h and .m for custom cell:

```
@interface InscriptionCustomCell : UITableViewCell {

IBOutlet UILabel *titreCell;
IBOutlet UITextField *contenuCell;
```

}

@property(nonatomic,retain) UILabel *titreCell;
@property(nonatomic,retain) UITextField *contenuCell;

@end

And when I try to use it with my tableView:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"InscriptionCustomCell";

InscriptionCustomCell *cell = (InscriptionCustomCell*) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}
//[cell.textLabel setText:@"Cell"];
// Configure the cell...

if(indexPath.section ==0)
{
    [cell.titreCell setText:[model.listModuleInfoPerso objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [cell.contenuCell setPlaceholder:[model.listModuleInfoPerso objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}else {
    [cell.titreCell setText:[model.listModuleInfoSupp objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [cell.contenuCell setPlaceholder:[model.listModuleInfoSupp objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}
return cell;
```

}

I have an error:

```
reason: '-[UITableViewCell titreCell]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b5f430'
```

Why? My custom cell is own statement!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}
```

You are creating a UITableViewCell instance not your custom cell.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (cell == nil) {
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCell"owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}
```